# How do I access this rootScope in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this code, the controller is being supplied an injected scope and rootScope, so why does it fail on the last line with:

ReferenceError: $rootscope is not defined

```
angular.module("myEntity").controller('productsCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'MyAction', '$rootScope', function ($scope, MyAction, $rootScope) {
        $scope.propertyValue = something;
        $scope.canDoSomething = $rootscope.myRootScopeProperty = 1;
        ....
```

Comment: it's ```$rootScope``` (capital S), you have a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Just convert this

```
$rootscope
```

to this

```
$rootScope
```

Answer (score 1):

change `$rootscope` to `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

here error is $rootscope, so we need to change it to $rootScope.,

**problem:**

```
$scope.canDoSomething = $rootscope.myRootScopeProperty = 1;
```

> ReferenceError: $rootscope is not defined

**solution:**

```
$scope.canDoSomething = $rootScope.myRootScopeProperty = 1;
```